# How to display json output of SELECT statement in the same window of vscode just by keyboard?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using VS Code for querying the database, etc.. because its way lighter and versatile than VS and better UI than SSMS.

I read how to work with [queries in msserver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver16#insert-and-query).

Here is the vscode-mssql [extension wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/wiki).

I have a simple request with json output like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Persons 
FOR JSON PATH
```

I can run it by `CTRL + ALT + E` and the output is in new editor window as following:

[image: Output]

Now to see the formated content I have to click on the line and it opens new tab, usually in the editor window with the SQL request and with every click, it opens new tab.. So when you change the request, you have to click again, and it opens new tab.

This bothers me enough, but on top of that, when I want to close the tab with formated result, which behaves like normal new tab with text, I have to answer dialog with question whether I want to save the changes.

Is there any way of just being able to jumping to the JSON output window and refreshing it with every run of the script? Because standard query with tabular results are always refreshed, works great and you can close it just with `Ctrl + W` and I like to control the environment more or less with keyboard. (Ctrl + 1, Ctrl + Alt + Right, etc..)

I'm thinking about [contributing](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/wiki/contributing) somehow [new features](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/new).

Customization of [shortcuts](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/wiki/customize-shortcuts) is not enough I guess.

Thank you for some suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately i believe you will have to go down this contributing and new features path, because vs code opens a new JSON file for you to read the json, and the json file is a normal unsaved file, it will always get prompt to save. You can try to get use to instead of just `CTRL W` to close, you will have to press `CTRL W RightArrow Enter`

Comment: Yeah the closing of one file is fine, but multiple unsaved tabs with no indication what is where is.. So at least I didn't overlook something. It would be sufficient to setup opening of the json in the same tab instead of opening new and new and new with every next click.

Comment: With the closing, thanks to your mentioning I realized slight improvement of less moving to `Ctrl W -> Right arrow -> Space` :D

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl+W` is bound to the command `workbench.action.closeActiveEditor` (**View: Close Editor**)

There are 2 other close commands that might do what you want: Just Close, don't ask to save:

- `workbench.action.revertAndCloseActiveEditor`
- `workbench.action.toggleConfirmBeforeClose`

You can create a key binding for editors with JSON files:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+w",
  "command": "workbench.action.revertAndCloseActiveEditor",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'json'"
}
```